# Rational Rhapsody C++/cli template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, rhapsody

I am junior programmer and now we are starting new project **using Rational Rhapsody** for architecture plans. I am used to **use C++/CLI** because of .net form apps and now I have problem with connection between Rational Rhapsody and Microsoft **Visual studio 2010**. It still **damages my codes** etc. For example, move some pieces of code and put them in wrong parts of class, so I could not compile my solution.

My question is: **Is there any Rational Rhapsody template for C++/CLI?**

Thank you for following responses.

PS: This is also my first thread on this server, so be patient with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made small research and also write some E-Mails with IBM technical support and I find out sad thing. If you are making GUI in C++/CLI in Microsoft visual studio 2010 and you are using Rational Rhapsody, **it is recommended to create C++/CLI GUI separately from libraries**. So There are two ways how to solve it:

**A)** Work with whole project, but do not make round-trips with GUI, only in final version, export GUI to Rational Rhapsody

**B)** Make only libraries with Rational Rhapsody and second project will be GUI which will have those libraries included.

I am trying first way, so if I find something interesting, I will try to share it.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Rational Rhapsody is very specific. I also worked one time in a company with this case tool. For such questions like yours there is the support line. They solved my problems very fast

Comment: Well, I have contacted them, it take them about half day to response (time zone offset), but they do not discover anything. They are still writing me mails, that they are working on it and asking developers about it, but it is one week and they still do not found any suitable solution. And I think that thing I have written upper is only one solution of this problem. They send me two threads with this theme and one of them was this thread :). So they could response you only to questions they have in manuals. But it is fine that they are really polite.